# Convert the Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
ID Date

001 01/12/2010
002 15/12/2010
....
```

DateFormat: dd/mm/yyyy

I want to change the dateformat like mm/dd/yy by using select query

```
Select id, date from table1
```

Expected Output

```
ID Date

001 12/01/2010
002 12/15/2010
....
```

How to make a query for the above format.

Need Query Help.

Comment: What does the table look like please? You want this for output or for update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to specify a mm/dd format, like 101:

```
select  CONVERT(varchar(30), YourColumn, 101)
```

If your table stores dates as a string, you'd have to convert the string to a date first, like:

```
select  CONVERT(varchar(30), CONVERT(datetime, YourColumn), 101)
```